# Long canonical Q&A with a wrong answer, but the right answer is even longer (when is a very long answer justified?)

Tags: discussion, answers, old-questions, wrong-answers

Q&A in question: [*Multiple wildcards on a generic methods makes Java compiler (and me!) very confused*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546745/multiple-wildcards-on-a-generic-methods-makes-java-compiler-and-me-very-confu).

Brief explanation of how it's wrong:

- The *non-technical* summary in the beginning of the answer is fine.
- The *technical* reasoning in the later section, **Appendix: The rules of capture conversion**, is a misinterpretation of the specification.

  They've missed a few important sections of the specification which clearly explain it otherwise. (And I suppose I should point out these sections *did* exist at the time the answer was written.)

  There are also a few choice quotes that show that polygenelubricants' interpretation is wrong.

To sum it up, the question asks:

> Am I misunderstanding the capture conversion rules for wildcards?

*Yes*, and the answer misunderstands it too.

It's not completely incorrect, but the misinterpretation leaves the reader with a wrong idea of a what a particular feature means.

[Some of the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546745/multiple-wildcards-on-a-generic-methods-makes-java-compiler-and-me-very-confu#comment3715756_3547372) shed light on the situation as well:

> I'm actually not quite sure if my answer is correct, now. I'm getting more and more confused […]. I think my answer is partly wrong. I'm keeping this up to inspire others to investigate.
>
> Okay I think I finally got this now. Sorry if I caused confusion with the recursive capture conversion thing (which I'm still not sure what it's all about); I was thoroughly confused myself […].

The revision history shows polygenelubricants posted an initial answer with the incorrect technical reasoning, then added the correct non-technical summary, but retained the incorrect section.

---

So, the problem here is that the question is extremely long.

Nowadays, I suppose it could be closed as 'too broad'. But maybe this depends on who you ask, since I guess there are proponents of the idea that a good answer justifies a somewhat off-topic question. Also it's self-answered, but it wasn't posted this way. Instead, it seems like it started out small and inflated over time.

A complete answer (which I've written, but did not post since I had doubts about whether I should or not) turned out to be a bit longer than the *question and answer combined*. It's about the size of a blog post. (But I don't have a blog and I don't have interest in having one.)

I don't see a viable way to make the answer shorter, because the question asks about so many things.

I could write a short answer that refuted the mistakes in polygenelubricants' answer, but I don't want to do this. I'd rather the answer stood on its own, and I also have a lot of respect for this user so I didn't want to focus too much on how their answer is wrong. I just want to post a right one.

Some other considerations:

- I could post a comment, but likely nobody would see it. (Also, as I said before, I feel like the question deserves a proper answer.)
- I could edit the answer (note: heavily), but polygenelubricants' profile says they prefer to receive comments and fix errors themselves. They have not visited the site since 2013 so it seems unlikely they will fix it themselves. I assume they would also not have time, even if they did see the comment.
- I could let it go, but then the Q&A is just there hanging around being not quite right and not worth linking to. I think a good answer would be useful as a resource, for whoever wants to read it.

I don't really have a problem with not posting my answer. I wouldn't feel like my time was wasted.

Should I post my answer or possibly do something else?

(Maybe I should put less thought in to it? : / )

Comment: If the Q is broken then you have limited options, editing tends to break the existing answers.  Just post your own Q+A pair the way you think it should be done and vote the old Q+A as dup.

Comment: @HansPassant That's an interesting take, particularly marking it as a duplicate. (I can do that?) I have a Java gold badge now but I guess it seems like the kind of thing some people might grumble about.

Comment: Yes, be careful, you don't want to hammer it until your Q+A can be considered canonical.  You can fake a "Possible duplicate" comment.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried that once and it didn't work. I forgot what restriction I hit. Maybe it was that the dup target must be upvoted.

Comment: This is asking the wrong question. Instead, we should be asking "when is a *short* answer justified?" The more detail provided in an answer, the better. SO seeks to be a *complete* reference site, after all.

Comment: How come you haven't downvoted the answer, if you think it's wrong? There are a grand total of _zero_ downvotes on it.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit Seems kind of pointless. I haven't really taken any action on this Q&A, I rediscovered it about a week ago and have just been eying it basically. But anyway I've downvoted it so now it has -1. ;p Thanks for the reminder, I guess.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit I mean, to expand a little: my action thus far has been inaction, because to be honest I don't really know what should be done. The Q&A has been around for a long time so I didn't feel a sense of urgency--except that Java doesn't have good (thorough) canonical Qs on the subjects involved. Ultimately I came here for advice.

Comment: I approve of this metaquestion. However, regardless, if you think a post is wrong, downvote it. That's just fundamental. You don't need a consensus for that: the fact that votes sum to produce a final score already takes care of that.

Answer (score 3):

For a Q&A that supposedly needs heavy editing, that one seems to have garnered a healthy number of upvotes, on both the question and the answer, as well as several highly complimentary comments.

That said, if you are aware of *factual* errors in either the question or answer, it seems to me that this is the right answer:

> I could edit the answer (note: heavily)

I never have taken the time to really sit down and gain a full understanding of Java's wildcard syntax for generics, so I don't personally know what kinds of edits would be needed specifically in the question or answer. But when it comes to documenting a technical issue, there's generally not a lot of room for interpretation.

Granted, some documentation is easier to understand than others, and people don't always interpret it correctly. But assuming you are confident that it is you who are interpreting the technical data correctly and not the OP on that question, you should not only feel the right, but *encouraged* to make changes to fix technical, factual errors in the Q&A.

I do emphasize *factual*. For any change you make, you should be able to reference a specific piece of documentation (manual, specification, etc.) that supports your change.

(I don't mean you should necessarily actually include such references in your edits, though maybe in some places that would be appropriate…just that they should exist and you should know where they are).

As for your concern here…

> …but polygenelubricants' profile says they prefer to receive comments and fix errors themselves. They have not visited the site since 2013 so it seems unlikely they will fix it themselves. I assume they would also not have time, even if they did see the comment.

Preferences are just that. The rules of the site are clear: if you have the privileges to edit a post, and there is a good justification for doing so, you may. Just because the person who posted the post would *prefer* you not to, that doesn't mean you can't.

Plus, if they haven't even visited the site for 18 months, your guess that they may not see your comment could be correct (though, they may still be receiving email notifications about activity).

If I were you: I would post a comment outlining some of my more significant concerns, and suggesting the OP fix them or ask if they'd mind if I did. Wait a few days, or maybe even a week, to see if they respond. If not, go for it.

If they do respond, work with them to try to clean up the problems. If that proves impossible, consider just posting a new answer with your corrections. Technically, you could still edit their posts, but you run the risk of getting into a pointless edit/revert battle, and for sure you'd step on some toes unnecessarily.

Just my two cents. Full disclosure: I've only really been active on SO for about six months, so I may not completely grok the culture. But the above reflects both my understanding of the community standards and my own preferences for making sure publicly available information is accurate.

Comment: As a side note, I don't think the number of upvotes means much here. Let's just say I've gotten the feeling a lot of people don't fully understand the specification for wildcards and it looks like the blind leading the blind to me. Regarding the editing, I think the overall answer could be kept but most of it needs to be altered somehow. The conclusions are generally correct but the language law is all wrong. (I'm not entirely sure what the author was trying to say originally, except that it looks like they were guessing.)